# Expected ')' in aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkboxlist

I'm getting an error "Expected ')' "

The page is loaded successfully but in the browser footer Status "Done with errors"

**.aspx**

```
<td align="left" valign="top" style="width: 18%;">
   <div id="Div2" style="overflow:auto;height:120px;">
       <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chklstCourse" DataTextField="CourseName" DataValueField="CourseName" runat="server"></asp:CheckBoxList>
   </div>
</td>

<td align="left" valign="top" style="width: 18%;">
    <div id="Div4" style="overflow:auto;height:120px;">
       <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chklstCategory" DataTextField="Category" DataValueField="Category" runat="server"></asp:CheckBoxList>
    </div>
</td>
<td align="left" valign="top" style="width: 18%;">
    <div id="Div5" style="overflow:auto;height:120px;">
         <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chklstSubCat" DataTextField="SubCategory" DataValueField="SubCategory" runat="server"></asp:CheckBoxList>
    </div>
</td>
```

**View Source:**

```
<tr>
                <td><input id="ctl00_PageMainContent_filterPane_content_chklstCourse_0" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$PageMainContent$filterPane_content$chklstCourse$0" checked="checked" onclick="SelectAll(&#39;ctl00_PageMainContent_filterPane_content_chklstCourse&#39;,0);" /><label for="ctl00_PageMainContent_filterPane_content_chklstCourse_0">Select All</label></td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td><input id="ctl00_PageMainContent_filterPane_content_chklstCourse_1" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$PageMainContent$filterPane_content$chklstCourse$1" checked="checked" onclick="SelectAll(&#39;ctl00_PageMainContent_filterPane_content_chklstCourse&#39;,7 Habits of Highly Effective People);" /><label for="ctl00_PageMainContent_filterPane_content_chklstCourse_1">7 Habits of Highly Effective People</label></td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td><input id="ctl00_PageMainContent_filterPane_content_chklstCourse_2" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$PageMainContent$filterPane_content$chklstCourse$2" checked="checked" onclick="SelectAll(&#39;ctl00_PageMainContent_filterPane_content_chklstCourse&#39;,Advanced Networking for EBI/DVM);" /><label for="ctl00_PageMainContent_filterPane_content_chklstCourse_2">Advanced Networking for EBI/DVM</label></td>
            </tr><tr>
```

In view source in checkboxlist control onclick event added automatically, any problem behind this?

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: "Done with errors" generally mean's there is a scripting problem (JavaScript) not an ASP.NET one - the page wouldn't compile at all if that were the issue.

Comment: The problem is definitely in this string: SelectAll(&#39;ctl00_PageMainContent_filterPane_content_chklstCourse&#39;,Advanced Networking for EBI/DVM); as the system encodes "'" into &#39; somewhy. You should provide condebehind related to the chklstCourse.

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter in these two function calls is wrapped in quotes (`&#39;`), does the second need to be as well?

```
SelectAll(&#39;ctl00_PageMainContent_filterPane_content_chklstCourse&#39;,Advanced Networking for EBI/DVM);
SelectAll(&#39;ctl00_PageMainContent_filterPane_content_chklstCourse&#39;,7 Habits of Highly Effective People);
```

The second parameters look like a strings, but they aren't quoted.